# How to split edges without changing normals?

Tags: normals, edges, faces

I want to detach a head from my character (i'm making modular heads for my game) - to do this, i split edges ('Edge Split') around neck, select only the head and press P to detach. It works, but it is very noticeable in place where edges were splitted - i guess because normals of these edges were changed while splitting. 
Is there a way to split edges AND retain smooth transition between splitted faces (just like it was before splitting)?

[image: Visible normals after splitting]

Comment: In version 2.74 you have a normal edit modifier that you can transfer normals from the mesh that is without splitted edge, both meshes have to be in same location and on the new model you need to enable autosmooth in object data panel.

Comment: Thanks, finally i've found some time to test this, and i can't get it work. I've tried all possible setups (radial, directional) and i set the source object, but it do not copy normals. Is there some examples how to transfer normals? I've also tried Data Transfer modifier, but it also don't work at all...